# Accidentally backed Docker Postgres up with -v flag. How to restore?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, backup

I had a backup script for a small server running Postgresql in a Docker Container.
The backup line was the following:

> docker exec -t crm-database-1 pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:**************@localhost:5432/********** -F c -b -Z 9 -E UTF8 **-v** > $path/db.bak

Today the unthinkable happened and the Postgres data directory got corrupted. No chance of recovering.

I think I screwed myself because of the -v flag.

And of course I never tried to recover my backups before.

Now that im trying to restore one of the 20 Dumps I have but I only get errors like "unexpected EOF" or "file is not an archive"

Is there any chance on recovering or did I screw up and the data is gone?

I tried every possible combination of piping the backup to pg_restore or pg_ctl.
Also tried to edit the backup file by removing all "pg_dump: reading table..." with regex.

None did work.

EDIT:

After a long search i found out after "cat-ing" out something from docker to host, the file that gets created on the host, has a few bytes more.
With HxD I found, there are extra 0D (LineBreak) characters.
After removing them I was able to restore the schema but when trying to import data, I get the error message "out of memory"
Im going to dig a little bit more into that.

Comment: Why would some verbose messages from pgdump wreck your file system?

Comment: `-v` will add times and more detailed information to file but they will be in the form of comments so they do not cause an issue.   FYI, `pg_ctl` has nothing to do with  restoring. **Add to question**: 1) The pg_restore command used. 2) The complete error message(s) or at least a sample of them. 3) The result if you do `pg_restore -f db.sql db.bak`..

Comment: 1: pg_restore command used: `docker exec -i db-test-db-1 pg_restore -U postgres -v -v -d ********< db.bak`
2:  Error Message:
`pg_restore: allocating AH for (stdio), format 0
pg_restore: attempting to ascertain archive format
pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive`
3: 
`pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive`

Comment: 1) Per my previous comment this information needs to be `-->` **added to question** `<--`. 2) Don't use the redirect  `<`, just do `...-d ******** db.bak`.